# What does the function (lambda () 16) do?

Tags: lambda, racket

```
(lambda () 16)
```

This only returns `#<procedure>`
I think it returns 16 whatever we input. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: There's no input. It can be called in exactly one way, with no parameters. And yes, it returns 16, unless CPU is bugged, your Scheme is acting up, a cosmic ray hits your computer at just the right time, or something else extraordinary happens.

Comment: What do you mean “prove it”? If you want an informal explanation, there’s not much to say: the function as written takes no arguments and returns `16`, and it does nothing else. We can see that by simple inspection alone, given the definition of `lambda`. If you want a formal proof, well, you could translate the Racket expression to some formal system (e.g. a lambda calculus) and prove something in that setting, but that seems rather unhelpful given the simplicity of the expression and the triviality of the proof. What are you really trying to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test your assumptions by calling the returned procedure. The syntax for calling a function or a procedure `f` is `(f ...)`, where `...` stands for the arguments. Here, there are no arguments, so it would be simply `(f)`. You can tests your program from the Read-Eval-Print-Loop (REPL):

```
> (define f (lambda () 16))
> (f)
```

You can also simply call the anonymous function directly by wrapping it in parentheses:

```
> ((lambda () 16))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function by

```
((lambda () 16) 17) ;; or put instead of 17 whatever
```